# How do I add BrowserRouter in index.js file of a react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried using the following code to add Routes to my app. I added BrowserRouter to index.js file of my react app as follows,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const app = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.
```

Can anyone let me know why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your are passing an *object* to the render method, which expects

> a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components)

like the error message says.

Before:

```
const app = (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

After:

```
const app = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply...But I tried this too... and it still gives error... Even if i add the above code inside ReactDOM.render, it still throws error

Comment: I have seen tutorials and they have used the above code only and it worked for them. I can't find what problem I have in the code:(

Comment: Try this ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: yes I have tried that too... I have mentioned in the comment above.. It still gives error :(

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the app component ? Try replacing the <App /> component by a placeholder like <p>Hello</p>. Or check the basic example from the React Router docs https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Comment: when am using that it's working : ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><h1>Hello</h1></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Also if I just render App without BrowserRouter it's working perfectly fine..

Comment: The code in this question is already fixed, I can't reproduce your error, so I assume the problem to be in the <App /> component that you are importing.

Comment: hmmm... sure will look into it then... Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It works for me

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App component

```
export default App
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.. But this didn't work for me ... It still gives the same error

Comment: probably the problem is in App component, add it to check. Do you have export default App there?

Comment: yes ... i rectified my mistake... it was in the app component only...